# Scala: Cannot resolve overloaded constructor `ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]`

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I' m using Scala:2.12.16 and Flink:1.14.4.
I want to create a self-defined Trigger in Flink. But idea gave me error:

```
Cannot resolve overloaded constructor `ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]`
```

on

```
val intervalDesc:ReducingStateDescriptor[Long] = new ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]("fire-time", Min(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE)
val maxCountDesc:ReducingStateDescriptor[Long] = new ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]("count", Sum(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE)
```

The full code is shown below:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ReducingStateDescriptor
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.LongSerializer
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.{Trigger, TriggerResult}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.Window
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

class LqWaterLevelTrigger[W <: Window] extends Trigger[Object, W]{
  val log:Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  val interval:Long
  val maxCount:Long
  val intervalDesc:ReducingStateDescriptor[Long] = new ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]("fire-time", Min(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE)
  val maxCountDesc:ReducingStateDescriptor[Long] = new ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]("count", Sum(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE)


  override def onElement(element: Object, timestamp: Long, window: W, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): TriggerResult = ???

  override def onProcessingTime(time: Long, window: W, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): TriggerResult = ???

  override def onEventTime(time: Long, window: W, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): TriggerResult = ???

  override def clear(window: W, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): Unit = ???
}

case class Min() extends ReduceFunction[Long]  {
  override def reduce(value1: Long, value2: Long): Long = {
    Math.min(value1, value2)
  }
}

case class Sum() extends ReduceFunction[Long] {
  override def reduce(value1: Long, value2: Long): Long = {
    value1 + value2
  }
}
```

And here is how the `ReducingStateDescriptor` is defined in Java:

```
@PublicEvolving
public class ReducingStateDescriptor<T> extends StateDescriptor<ReducingState<T>, T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final ReduceFunction<T> reduceFunction;

    
    public ReducingStateDescriptor(
            String name, ReduceFunction<T> reduceFunction, Class<T> typeClass) {
        super(name, typeClass, null);
        this.reduceFunction = checkNotNull(reduceFunction);

        if (reduceFunction instanceof RichFunction) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "ReduceFunction of ReducingState can not be a RichFunction.");
        }
    }

    
    public ReducingStateDescriptor(
            String name, ReduceFunction<T> reduceFunction, TypeInformation<T> typeInfo) {
        super(name, typeInfo, null);
        this.reduceFunction = checkNotNull(reduceFunction);
    }

    // this is the constructor that I want
    public ReducingStateDescriptor(
            String name, ReduceFunction<T> reduceFunction, TypeSerializer<T> typeSerializer) {
        super(name, typeSerializer, null);
        this.reduceFunction = checkNotNull(reduceFunction);
    }

    
    public ReduceFunction<T> getReduceFunction() {
        return reduceFunction;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return Type.REDUCING;
    }
}
```

How to transform the scala code to eliminate the errors?

---

I add
`import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._`.

And the code turned to be :

```
val intervalDesc = new ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]("fire-time", Min(), createTypeInformation[Long]) //LongSerializer.INSTANCE
val maxCountDesc= new ReducingStateDescriptor[Long]("count", Sum(), createTypeInformation[Long])
```

with no errors.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using Scala 2.12.16, not 2.2.16.

Since Flink doesn't support Scala 2.12.16 out of the box, have you re-compiled Flink with Scala 2.12.16 support?

Comment: @MartijnVisser Nope. Is there any guide to recompile Flink with Scala?

Comment: You need to check out the Flink source code and then build it via `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Djapicmp.skip -Dscala-2.12 -Dscala.version=2.12.16`